# react-virtualized infinite loop of scrollbar disappearing/reappearing

Tags: reactjs, resize, react-virtualized

I am currently using react-virtualized to render huge lists. When I resize and reach a certain width, there is a point where the scrolling bar infinitely disappears and reappears even though the width calculated stays the same. This could be an error within the react-virtualized library, but I am trying to find a work-around. Here is what I have right now within my render method:

```
// The onResize is what I am currently focusing on
<AutoSizer disableHeight onResize={this.setDimensions}>
        {({ width }) => {
          return (
            <div id={id} style={{ width: this.state.containerWidth }}>
              <InfiniteLoader
                isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded}
                loadMoreRows={handleInfiniteLoad}
                rowCount={sheetsTotalCount} // all elements, not only the loaded
                threshold={3} // starts loading the new data within 3 rows from the bottom
                minimumBatchSize={3}
              >
                {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
                  <WindowScroller scrollElement={scrollElement}>
                    {({ height, scrollTop }) => (
                      <List
                        autoHeight
                        height={height || defaultHeight}
                        ref={registerChild}
                        rowCount={this.state.numRows}
                        rowHeight={this.state.cardHeight + 2 * marginBetweenCards}
                        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer} // renders the rows
                        scrollTop={scrollTop}
                        width={this.state.containerWidth}
                        onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                        className="oh outline-none"
                      />
                    )}
                  </WindowScroller>
                )}
              </InfiniteLoader>
              {sheetsTotalCount > 0 &&
                sheetsAreLoading &&
                renderLoadingIndicator()}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </AutoSizer>
```

When using the onResize prop, I end up getting the infinite disappear/reappear error as the code attempts to do a series of calculations.

```
setDimensions = ({ width }) => {
    const { sheetList } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      containerWidth: width > 0 ? width : defaultWidth
    },() => { 
      this.setState({numCols: Math.max(Math.floor(this.state.containerWidth / baseThumbnailWidth), 1) }, () => {
        this.setState({numRows: Math.ceil(sheetList.size / this.state.numCols)}, () => {
          this.setState({cardWidth: Math.floor(this.state.containerWidth / this.state.numCols - 2 * marginBetweenCards)}, () => {
            this.setState({cardHeight: Math.round(this.state.cardWidth * thumbnailProportion)});
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Edit: I was able to solve my problem reducing the width on certain window dimensions. I think it could be an issue with react-virtualized and the issue that most resembles what I was dealing with was from the issue shown from Wessel

Comment: You don't say how you implemented rowRenderer, so I'm not sure this is the answer, but did you verify that you apply the style from the function arguments of rowRenderer to the returned element, as per https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1327#issuecomment-463167513 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're nesting so many `setStates`. And every time one of your states updates, it renders your list again, and the fact that you're nesting it 5 times seems dangerous.

Is there no way to pre-calculate everything and then call `setState` and update all your properties at once? I would give that a try.